# DriverManager.getConnection returns null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to use a Java class that already worked great for me in the past in order to access MySQL from my JSP project, running Tomcat 6. The problem is, that this line:

```java
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "password");
```

gives con a value of null.

Now, my question is - what can cause the "getConnection" method return null?

**Edit**: I see now that also, I get the infamous ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
I have the connector included in my build path. So why am I getting this error? And, does it have to do with getConnection returning null?

Comment: AFAIK Nothing can cause it to return `null`. You are more than likely swallowing an exception.

Comment: Having something on your build path not necessarily means it is on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the driver before you can get a connection from the DriverManager.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is incomplete. The `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` should be followed by the database name.

Trouble shoot steps:

1. Check the port
2. Check if the db server is turned on

Comment: the database name is not mandatory. if you want to use connections with different database schemes, you omit the name and place it into the query: 'SELECT * FROM <database>.<table>'

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `JDBC 3` then you need to load the driver like

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If you are working with `JDBC 4` then you are no longer required to manually load the JdbcDriver.

And then pass valid [connection_url](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#db_connection_url) to `getConnection`

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDbName", "root", "password");
```

Lastly make sure that `mysql driver jar` is in classpath.

Answer (score -1):

According to this  article(which has a good example) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html,

"con" will be null if the getConnection throws an exception and is caught in your code.

Like:

```
Connection con = null;
 try{ 
con = DriveManager.getConnection("Not right url");   

}catch(SQLException sqlE){};
System.out.println(con); //it will be null
```

you need to do

```
   connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
          + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
```

So maybe have "user = root&password = password"

Also if there is ClassNotFoundException most likely you need a jar file

DriverManager API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)

Comment: (if there is something wrong with answer please put why thank you)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your link is irrelevant to this question (and if it was you should at least have quoted or summarized the relevant parts) and `DriverManager.getConnection` by specification never returns `null`. You can verify this by looking at the `DriverManager` code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In my answer I said if getConnection is not done properly it is going to return null because most likely of a connection error, it looks like his string is not appropriate as the parameter is not done right, but it also could be he doesn't have a jar file, it is pretty much like the link you provided to him

Comment: But `DriverManager.getConnection()` is **never** going to return `null`. It either returns a `Connection` instance, or it throws an `SQLException`.